# How to cast complex datatype in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a complex data type column in hive table  which is struct and inside struct i have decimal datatype. I want to cast this struct(decimal(10,0)) into struct(double) or struct(float) when i am doing insert overwrite operation with another table.How can i achieve that because when i am trying its giving me an error-

```
 FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:23 Cannot insert into 
 target table because column number/types are different 'avro_poc_orc_test': Cannot convert column 3 from struct<latitude:decimal(28,2),longitude:decimal(19,3)> to struct<latitude:double,longitude:double>.
```

Is it possible to cast complex datatype to another complex datatype?

Answer (score 2):

Construct the struct from its components while casting the relevant field

#### Demo

```
with t as (select struct(cast (123 as decimal(10,0)),222,333,444) as s)

select  struct(cast(t.s.col1 as double),t.s.col2,t.s.col3,t.s.col4) 
from    t
;
```

Comment: What if already have array of struct and i need to cast every decimal element of this array of struct into float.In that case how to proceed?